# Using hypothesis and py.test to test compound strategies in python, must I test them one at a time?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-hypothesis

I have 3 files, module.py which contains an example function that tests whether an input is numeric. I have a file called test_mymodule_long.py that *successfully* tests and passes several types of inputs using **[py.test](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/)** and **[hypothesis](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis-python/)**. I'm using Python 3.6, but this shouldn't matter (if you're not, just remove the type hinting). For this particular function, it's not helpful to me to have these split up; if hypothesis finds an edge case, I just want to know the offending input and the exception raised. Thus, I'd like to write this test as indicated in test_mymodule_short.py, but this doesn't work.

My question is this: Is there a way to write strategies in hypothesis more efficiently than in test_mymodule_long.py?

Here is the code in each file:

```
'''
mymodule.py
'''

from typing import Union

Number = Union[int, float]


def is_numeric(x: Number):
    try:
        y = float(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False

# -------------------------------------------

'''
test_mymodule_long.py [This code works]
(using pytest to discover tests automatically)
'''
from hypothesis import given, example
import hypothesis.strategies as st
import mymodule

@given(st.integers())
def test_is_numeric_integer(num):
    result = stats.is_numeric(num)
    assert isinstance(result, bool)


@given(st.floats())
def test_is_numeric_float(num):
    result = stats.is_numeric(num)
    assert isinstance(result, bool)


@given(st.text())
def test_is_numeric_text(num):
    result = stats.is_numeric(num)
    assert isinstance(result, bool)


@given(st.lists(st.floats()))
def test_is_numeric_list(num):
    result = stats.is_numeric(num)
    assert isinstance(result, bool)

# -------------------------------------------

'''
test_mymodule_short.py [This code fails!]
(using pytest to discover tests automatically)
'''
from hypothesis import given, example
import hypothesis.strategies as st
import mymodule

@given(st.integers())
@given(st.floats())
@given(st.text())
@given(st.lists(st.floats()))
def test_is_numeric_list(num):
    result = mymodule.is_numeric(num)
    assert isinstance(result, bool)
```

Note that I don't think the error message really matters here, it's more of a *this-isn't-how-you-do-it* situation and I'm seeking advice on whether there is a compact way to test one function with multiple hypothesis strategies. In addition, I know that a proper is_numeric function would be programmed differently (assuming you really even needed such a function). I also know that the tests indicated here would not be sufficiently complete to know whether it worked. These are just examples to make my question clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to use multiple strategies for a single test, but you *can* combine multiple strategies into a single one and use that in your tests - the `one_of` strategy. So you could write something like the following:

```
from hypothesis import given, example
import hypothesis.strategies as st
import mymodule

@given(st.one_of(
    st.integers(), 
    st.floats(),
    st.text(),
    st.lists(st.floats()),
))
def test_is_numeric_list(num):
    result = mymodule.is_numeric(num)
    assert isinstance(result, bool)
```